# Gitflow with multiple release branches and staging environment

Tags: git, branching-and-merging, git-flow

So, I've read alot about gitflow.
One major issue is that it doesn't account for `staging` environment.
I can understand that `develop` branch is mirrored in `develop` environment and `master` branch is the `production` environment.

Those cases are easy because, there's only one `develop` branch and one `master` branch.
However, a project may have multiple `release/v*.*.*` branches, but one `staging` environment.
Which of the `release/` branches should I deploy on the `staging` environment? All? The first one?

How did you handle this issue, considering I don't want to manually decide each time I open a `release/` if to deploy it to `staging` or not. I'm looking for a rule of thumb or some other solution I haven't thought of.

Comment: Maybe this can help? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16562339/git-flow-and-master-with-multiple-parallel-release-branches

Comment: I don't see a solution or discussion regarding the relation between several release branches and a staging environment