# Is there a solution for handling non-linear release schedules with Git-flow?

Tags: git, version-control, merge, release

The Git flow model is working well for our company so far, but we're wondering about a solution for handling this hypothetical situation. I searched around a bit, but I think my lack of proper terminology for this case might have stymied my Google-fu.

If all your releases must "be from" a merge commit into the `master` branch, as detailed here:

[A successful Git branching model](http://nvie.com/posts/a-successful-git-branching-model/)

Then how do you handle a situation in which you release `0.2.0`, then `0.3.0`, then `0.2.1`? At this point must the release be performed from the 0.2.x development branch (assuming one exists, or is created from the `0.2.0` tag)? Certainly you can't merge back into master, as your patch release is probably a good few commits behind.

Is the best solution then, something like:

```
git checkout tag-release-0.2.0
git checkout -b some-0.2.1-critical-feature
.. (work) ..
git commit
# At this point, the release-0.2.x-branch is the same as the above release tag
git checkout release-0.2.x-branch
# Merge the feature branch into the patch release branch
git merge some-0.2.1-critical-feature
# NOTE here! Release occurs from the patch branch!
git tag tag-release-0.2.1
# Merge patch fixes into develop
git checkout develop
git merge tag-release-0.2.1
```

Is there a better solution than this? If the **RULE** is to merge into master to perform a release, won't any patch releases have to take place prior to the next minor/major?

Comment: Similar to my question http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16386323/following-git-flow-how-should-you-handle-a-hotfix-of-an-earlier-release, which still haven't got a really satisfactory answer.

Comment: The `git flow support` command I think kind of handles this situation... but I'm not sure it was ever properly finished...