# Git - Using multiple concurrent master/develop pairs and merging feature branches to both

Tags: git, merge, git-merge, git-flow, feature-branch

We have a code base for a grails plugin that actively supports two versions of grails. There are some core differences in the layout and configuration of each version, but the functionality provided by both should be near identical.

I would like to get our git workflow into a state where a feature can be developed against one version, and then easily merged against the other.

Using the layout discussed in [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18220663/advice-on-multiple-release-lines-and-git-flow-for-git-non-gurus), we have a pair of `master` and `develop` branches for both the `grails237` and `grails243` versions. What I'm aiming for is this:

[image: Git concurrent versions feature merge]

Is this possible to do this in such a way that only the `feature-xyz` changes are merged, and not any previous grails version-specific changes that come before it?

I realise that cherrypicking is an option, but for multiple changes it could get messy..

Comment: Yes, you would just merge `feature-xyz` exactly as the arrows indicate. What is the actual question?

Comment: There are significant configuration/architecture differences between the pairs before the feature, which need to remain unchanged. How do I avoid merging those older changes and only take the feature commits?

Comment: Likewise I run into this problem. Just merging feature-xyz will pull in the history of other changes from it's parent develop & master that I wouldn't want. I would only want the changes from feature-xyz, on the assumption that those changes have no major conflicts from architecture changes between the two root versions. In the end I have to cherry pick.