# Git - branching strategy for former releases?

Tags: git, version-control, branch, git-branch

How does one deal with the case of **former releases** that are not subject to be merged back to the main development branch ('*master*' by default)?

Could you point to some documentation that describes that?

Current question is using Git alone (not gitflow).

Comment: possible duplicate of [Advice on multiple release lines and git-flow, for git non-gurus](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18220663/advice-on-multiple-release-lines-and-git-flow-for-git-non-gurus)

Comment: It's worth noting that a lot of git users think git-flow puts a lot of unnecessary constraints.

Comment: If current post is "primarily opinion-based", why aren't those flagged the same? [Advice on multiple release lines and git-flow, for git non-gurus](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18220663/advice-on-multiple-release-lines-and-git-flow-for-git-non-gurus) [Following git-flow how should you handle a hotfix of an earlier release?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16386323/following-git-flow-how-should-you-handle-a-hotfix-of-an-earlier-release/16386527#16386527)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just leave that release in its own branch without merging to master and/or develop. Merging is not mandatory. If any subsequent development or fix should be added to that release you can use that release branch.

Comment: Thanks! And suppose there is a few man-months of work to do on this old release, shall I consider this old release branch like a kind of 'master' branch like in the model and create a 'develop' branch dedicated to this old release and so on? (I hope you follow me)

Comment: Exactly. Use that release branch as sort of master and branch off as many new dedicated branches as you need.